# Recognize swipe gesture in view not in subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have added a subview to a View Controller's view. This subview is the view of QLPreviewController.

What I am trying to achieve is to recognize swipe gestures on the subview **in the parent view**, i.e. the View Controller's view. In the end, I want to be able to swipe left /right on the view to load the next document for preview.

I'm aware of hit testing and understand that by just attaching a gesture recognizer to the parent view, those will not be recognized, since the **subview** will be the "hit-test" view.

Now what is the best (or easiest) way to recognize those gestures?
Note: I didn't manage to attach the gesture recognizers to the subview, this doesn't seem to work.

*** UPDATE ***

To make this more clear - this is the code from my ViewController. vContent is just a view in my ViewController, where I add the view of the QLPreviewController:

```
let pvVc = QLPreviewController()
pvVc.dataSource = self

vContent.addSubview(pvVc.view)
```

I tried adding the swipe recognizers both to the vContent and the pvVc.view. In both cases no event was fired.

```
let sgrLeft: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handleSwipe:"))
sgrLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
sgrLeft.delegate = self
```

On some other view the code works fine.

Any hint is appreciated!
Thx
Eau

Comment: What do you mean you didn't manage to attach the gesture to subview? What didn't work?

Comment: Also it would be good to have just one of the Swift/Objective-C tags, so the people can give you an answer based on your needs.

Comment: In your case delegate will be the good solution. Handle all gesture actions in parent view from sub view.

Comment: Ok, thx, I added more detail and removed one tag

Answer (score 2):

Well, the responder chain, the unknown animal … ;-)

You can subclass the superview and override `-hitTest:forEvent:`.

> You rarely need to call this method yourself, but you might override it to hide touch events from subviews.

Comment: Ok, so do I need to handle touchesBegin/End by myself?
In the end, I just want to handle swipe left /right and pass the other events through, because the view of the QLPreviewController needs to handle e.g. scrolling of previews documents

Comment: No, you simply can return self instead of sending the message to the subviews.

Answer (score 1):

Gesture Recognizers Get the First Opportunity to Recognize a Touch, so even the subview is hitTest view. the gestureRecognizer attached on superView can recognizer touch event.